# Setting SolidBrush Array

Tags: c#

I want to display the traffic lights color on the circles I have drawn on the PictureBox. To do this I have created an array that contains the colors I want to fill my circles with. However, it only seems to be filling green for all 3 of my circles. Any Help would be much appreciated.

Here is my Code:

```
private void btnDrawTLight_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int circleSize = int.Parse(txtRadius.Text) * 2;
        Graphics paper = ptbDiplay.CreateGraphics();
        Pen pen1 = new Pen(Color.Black, 2);
        //SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(Color.Red, Color.Yellow, Color.Green);
        Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(ptbDiplay.Width / 2, 5, circleSize, circleSize);
        SolidBrush[] traffic = 
        {
            new SolidBrush(Color.Red), 
            new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow), 
            new SolidBrush(Color.Green)
        };


        for (int i = 0; i <= trafficLights; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x <= traffic.Length; x++)
            {
                paper.FillEllipse(traffic[x], rec);
            }
            paper.DrawEllipse(pen1, rec);
            rec.Y += circleSize + GAP;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a radius.");
        txtRadius.Clear();
        txtRadius.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not modifying that Y inside the loop that actually changes the brush. It paints all three on the same spot, inevitably ending with painting it over in green. On that note, what is `trafficLights`?

Comment: shouldn't `for (int x = 0; x <= traffic.Length; x++)` be `for (int x = 0; x < traffic.Length; x++)`

Comment: What is `trafficLights`, and do you definitely need a nested loop? (Your bound for `x` is incorrect too - this code would throw an exception.)

Comment: trafficLight is just an integer value I created

Comment: You draw all three colours on top of each other for every light. You don't need the inner loop at all.

Comment: But what does it _mean_? It's only incrementing the Y for every step in that, which makes no sense, it should change that Y between brushes.

Comment: @DavidG Yup, turns out the loop was irrelevant, have already removed it and it works now. Appreciate the help everyone